# How Node caching is used to improve draw performance

Tags: kineticjs

I have been gone through some example of Kinecticjs, just for the sake of curosity, I need an answer about: 
How Node Caching helps in improving draw performance?

Answer (score 0):

A cached node is actually saved as an image.

Canvas can display an image much faster than it can calculate/redraw the details of a node.

The reason images draw faster:

- Images are consecutively grouped pixels that just need to be "bulk" copied from storage to the screen.
- Nodes (shapes) must be recalculated pixel by pixel and then drawn to the screen.